# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Message object in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have little to basic experience in python but I have to make a discord bot and I'm stuck with something that is probably really simple

```
@client.command()
async def submitclue(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Submit your answer')
    message, author, = await client.wait_for('message')
    if message.content == 'twopeople':
         ctx.send('Answer correct.')
    else:
         ctx.send('Answer wrong')
```

This is my code so far, It's pretty straight forward. Users would do "-submitclue" and the bot would reply with "Submit your answer" and if the answer matches the message.content the bot replies with "Answer Correct.

The problem is when I run this and tested in, I get this error

> message, author, = await client.wait_for('message')
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Message object

I tried searching everywhere on what that could be but had no luck. Would be great if someone could point me in the right way or fix it for me I've been stuck on this for the whole day now.

Answer (score 0):

`await client.wait_for('message')` returns only `message`. You can get author of the message using `message.author`.

```py
@client.command()
async def submitclue(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Submit your answer')
    message = await client.wait_for('message')
    print(f"{message.author} is an author of the message.")
    if message.content == 'twopeople':
         ctx.send('Answer correct.')
    else:
         ctx.send('Answer wrong')
```